# Creating a list with of documents that contain certain words in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with columns such as:

```
df =
title body
A     yellow, gree
B     blue, red
C     red, green
D     grey, blue
```

I would like to create a new dataframe with those rows that contain the word red:

```
df_New =
title body
B     blue, red
C     red, green
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
import pandas

Documents = pandas.read_csv(df.csv)

words = ['red', 'Red']

Df_New = Documents.str.match('(words)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```py
df_ = df[df['body'].str.contains('red', case=False)]
```

```
print(df_)

  title        body
1     B   blue, red
2     C  red, green
```